# Extract rows from pandas dataframe corresponding to list of month-day

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

This must have been asked before but I couldn't find what I'm looking for, apologies if duplicate. I have a dataframe `df` where the index is in python datetime:

```
1982-01-01  [282.7945979191705, 279.12373352050776, 277.74...
1982-01-02  [279.12373352050776, 277.7481374216604, 278.21...
1982-01-03  [277.7481374216604, 278.21691274118945, 276.85...
1982-01-04  [278.21691274118945, 276.85932268415183, 273.1...
1982-01-05  [276.85932268415183, 273.12550555218706, 273.4...
...
2001-12-27  [277.50443007919813, 274.45894647954583, 274.6...
2001-12-28  [274.45894647954583, 274.6708258324927, 275.59...
2001-12-29  [274.6708258324927, 275.59033873840997, 274.35...
2001-12-30  [275.59033873840997, 274.3595948271699, 274.92...
2001-12-31  [274.3595948271699, 274.92645028921316, 283.02...
```

Now I have a list of month-day `dates` I would like to filter with:

```
Index(['01-08', '01-23', '02-07', '02-22', '03-09', '03-24', '04-08', '04-23',
       '05-08', '05-23', '06-07', '06-22', '07-07', '07-22', '08-06', '08-21',
       '09-05', '09-20', '10-05', '10-20', '11-04', '11-19', '12-04', '12-19'],
      dtype='object')
```

How can I extract all the rows from the dataframe corresponding to these dates? I tried `df.loc[dates]` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Using `strftime`

```
yourdf=df[df.index.strftime('%m-%d').isin(dates)].copy()
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted! Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: New name I see :)

Comment: @Erfan ah :-) yes, feel boring using the same name

Answer (score 0):

Your `dates` is a Pandas series of type Objects. You can't compare a datetime series and an object series directly.

Instead, you should first use your dataframe's index to create a new column of type "object" that contains the corresponding month and day.

```
df['month-day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)  + "-" + pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).day.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Afterwards, you can use this new `month-day` column for filtering:

```
df[df["month-day"].isin(dates)]
```